# regular expression for searching filename in java

Tags: java

I need a regular expression to search for a filename with the format:
`abc_abc0003_2012-14-11_1212_regex.txt`. In the filename, `abc_abc0003_` and `_regex.txt` will be constant and the remaining portion will be variable.

The regular expression I have tried is:

`"abc_abc0003_" + "(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])" + "[_0-9]*" + "_regex.txt"`

This is working fine for the `matches()` function in Java, but when I use the same for searching filenames it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure whatever you're using for file search actually supports regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (pattern with `_`, digit and `-`), with reluctant (`+`) quantifier:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc_abc0003_[_\\d-]+?_regex.txt");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputStr);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try regex as below to allow `numbers`, `_` & `-` in between the two ends.

```
     ^(abc\\_abc0003\\_)[\\_\\-\\d]+(\\_regex\\.txt)$
```

e.g.

```
String regex12 = "^(abc\\_abc0003\\_)[\\_\\-\\d]+(\\_regex\\.txt)$";
Pattern pattern12 = Pattern.compile(regex12);
System.out.println(pattern12
                    .matcher("abc_abc0003_2012-14-11_1212_regex.txt")
                    .find());//prints true
System.out.println(pattern12
                    .matcher("abc_abc0003_2012-14-11_ab1212_regex.txt")
                    .find());//prints false
```

Comment: Isn't the OP trying to search for file names with that pattern within the input string? Or just trying to see if the input string matches that pattern?

Comment: @BheshGurung: I haven't put the code to be use. **The answer is around the regex ONLY**. Example is used to demonstrate that it allows `numbers, _ & -` only in between.

Comment: sorry yogendra singh its not working. i tried in matches() function and tfilelist which searches for files in specified folder

Comment: @123456: Can you share the example data and point what is not working?

Comment: String s="abc_abc0003_2012-14-11_1212_regex.txt";
if(s.toUpperCase().matches("^(abc\\_abc0003\\_)[\\_\\-\\d]+(\\_regex\\.txt)$"))
{
System.out.println("File Name Matching");
}
else
{
System.out.println("File Name is not Matching");
} it is file name is not matching

Comment: my main requirement is to search files with this pattern and copy from one location to another location

Comment: @123456: How will it match when you are converting your file name to upper case `s.toUpperCase()`? Change it to lowercase as you are using lowercase chars in your regex.

Comment: sorry it is working in matching but not working in searching in tfilelist

Comment: @123456: What do you mean by searching? Can you please share your code snippet for the search?

Comment: actually i am working in ETL tool Talend,in this tool we have one componenet named tfilelist which searches files based on given regex. for this tool java code will be generated at the back end.

Comment: @123456 Open the generated java code and validate if its doing extra encoding in the regex before using it. If it does, it will cause the issue.